# Bad practice to edit questions in triage queue?

Tags: discussion

Some questions in the triage review queue have issues that can easily be fixed by editing them (at least in part). Is it considered bad practice to edit these posts or is that part of the reason why they are there?

I guess a side note would be what types of things qualify a question for "should be improved" and "looks okay."

> **Edit:** The issue was that I didn't know of the help and improvement queue because I don't have access to it yet.

Answer (score 2):

If a question just needs a bit of editing cleanup by the community, mark it as Should Be Improved and it will be placed in a queue for community membors to edit it into shape.

The purpose of `Triage` is to direct questions to where they belong, not to *actually act on them*.  If a question just needs to be closed until the OP addressed significant core problems, it gets sent off to the Close Vote queue.  If it just needs the presentation cleaned up a bit and a bit of fine tuning, it can be sent of to the Help and Improvement queue.  If it's fine, it can leave the moderation systems entirely.